# Find a text within a pattern using awk in UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, pattern-matching

I have many text files with the 1st line being in the following format in individual files.

```
/*tablename-Employee*/ 
/*tablename-Department*/
/*tablename-Orders*/
```

I would like to fetch Employee, Department and Orders from each individual file using awk.

I tried this, but didn't see any output.

```
 awk '/^[\/]*tablename: / {print $1}' employee_file.sql
 awk '/^[\/]*tablename: / {print $1}' department_file.sql
 awk '/^[\/]*tablename: / {print $1}' order_file.sql
```

Expected Output from individual command.

```
Employee
Department
Orders
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F '[-*]' 'NR == 1{print $3}' file1
Employee

awk -F '[-*]' 'NR == 1{print $3}' file2
Department

awk -F '[-*]' 'NR == 1{print $3}' file3
Orders
```

Comment: I've 3 different  files containing the first line with pattern `/*tablename-`

Comment: just add exit after print

Comment: @anubhava the awk logic is working fine but I'm getting many whitespaces below the output.

Comment: See updated, `NR == 1` will make it run for 1st line only.

Comment: For efficiency, add `exit` after the `print` like @NahuelFouilleul suggested rather than adding `NR==1`.